# PHP string search and replace - possible use of DOM Needed

Tags: php, html

I cant seem to figure out how to achieve my goal.

I want to find and replace a specific class link based off of a generated RSS feed (need the option to replace later no matter what link is there)

Example HTML:

```
<a class="epclean1" href="#">
```

WHAT IT SHOULD LOOK LIKE:

```
<a class="epclean1" href="google.com">
```

May need to incorporate get element using DOM as the Full php has a created document. If that is the case I would need to know how to find by class and add the href url that way.

FULL PHP:

```
<?php 
$rss = new DOMDocument(); 
$feed = array();
$urlArray = array(array('url' => 'https://feeds.megaphone.fm')
);

foreach ($urlArray as $url) {
    $rss->load($url['url']);

        foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
            $item = array ( 
                'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue
                );
            array_push($feed, $item);
        }
    }

    usort( $feed, function ( $a, $b ) {
                return strcmp($a['title'], $b['title']); 
    });

    $limit = sizeof($feed);
    $previous = null;
    $count_firstletters = 0;
    for ($x = 0; $x < $limit; $x++) {
        $firstLetter = substr($feed[$x]['title'], 0, 1); // Getting the first letter from the Title you're going to print
        if($previous !== $firstLetter) { // If the first letter is different from the previous one then output the letter and start the UL
            if($count_firstletters != 0) {
                echo '</ul>'; // Closing the previously open UL only if it's not the first time
                echo '</div>';

            }
            echo '<button class="glanvillecleancollapsible">'.$firstLetter.'</button>';
            echo '<div class="glanvillecleancontent">';
            echo '<ul style="list-style-type: none">';
            $previous = $firstLetter;
            $count_firstletters ++;
        }   
        $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']); 
        echo '<li>'; 
        echo '<a class="epclean'.$i++.'" href="#" target="_blank">'.$title.'</a>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';  // Close the last UL
    echo '</div>';
    ?>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The above fullphp shows on site like so (this is shortened as there is 200+):

```
    <div class="modal-glanvillecleancontent">
        <span class="glanvillecleanclose">×</span>

    <p id="glanvillecleaninstruct">Select the first letter of the episode that you wish to get clean version for:</p>
    <br>


     <button class="glanvillecleancollapsible">8</button>
<div class="glanvillecleancontent">
<ul style="list-style-type: none">
<li><a class="epclean1" href="#" target="_blank">80's Video Vixen Tawny Kitaen 044</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<button class="glanvillecleancollapsible">A</button>
<div class="glanvillecleancontent">
<ul style="list-style-type: none">
<li><a class="epclean2" href="#" target="_blank">Abby Stern</a></li>
<li><a class="epclean3" href="#" target="_blank">Actor Nick Hounslow 104</a></li>
<li><a class="epclean4" href="#" target="_blank">Adam Carolla</a></li>
<li><a class="epclean5" href="#" target="_blank">Adrienne Janic</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: DOM is a better route, but your `preg_replace` fails because you aren't using delimiters.

Comment: what is `add_filter()`?

Comment: @billynoah I believe it’s a Wordpress thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm. I think your pattern and replacement might be your problem.

What you have

```
                $pattern = 'class="epclean1 href="(.*?)"';
                $replacement = 'class="epclean1 href="google.com"';
```

Fix

```
                $pattern = '/class="epclean1" href=".*"/';
                $replacement = 'class="epclean1" href="google.com"';
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not very clear about how your question relates to the code shown, but I don't see any attempt to replace the attribute within the DOM code. You'd want to look at XPath to find the desired elements:

```
function change_clean($content) {
    $dom = new DomDocument;
    $dom->loadXML($content);
    $xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
    $nodes = $xpath->query("//a[@class='epclean1']");
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        if ($node->getAttribute("href") === "#") {
            $node->setAttribute("href", "https://google.com/");
        }
    }
    return $dom->saveXML();
}

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?><foo><bar><a class="epclean1" href="#">test1</a></bar><bar><a class="epclean1" href="https://example.com">test2</a></bar></foo>';
echo change_clean($xml);
```

Output:

```
<foo><bar><a class="epclean1" href="https://google.com/">test1</a></bar><bar><a class="epclean1" href="https://example.com">test2</a></bar></foo>
```

Comment: quick question: if I were to want to use an ACR field value($post_url) instead of "https://google.com/" - How would I go about it?

Comment: I suppose just pass it to the function as an argument

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated